# I get an authentication failed message when I try to remove or install software

Tags: authentication

Whenever I try to install or remove software I end up getting an authentication failed message. I've already entered my password and it tells me authentication failed. I do know my password but for some reason it doesn't take it my log in and key ring are the same password, mainly since I'm the only one in my family who's comfortable with Linux.

```
foxxy_gunmage@Rei-Ayanami:~$ sudo ls
[sudo] password for foxxy_gunmage: 
Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for foxxy_gunmage: 
Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for foxxy_gunmage: 
Sorry, try again.
sudo: 3 incorrect password attempts
foxxy_gunmage@Rei-Ayanami:~$ groups
foxxy_gunmage adm dialout fax cdrom floppy tape audio dip video plugdev fuse netdev lpadmin nopasswdlogin admin sambashare vboxusers powerdev
foxxy_gunmage@Rei-Ayanami:~$
```

Comment: did you set Ubuntu to log in automatically without a password?

Comment: yes i did do i set it back? and how do i do that?

Comment: Did you make your password blank (i.e., zero characters long)? Please note that this is not the same thing as setting up Ubuntu to log you in automatically.

Comment: no its a string of eight characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem.
I thought this bug was fixed, but maybe not. Here is information I found while searching for a solution(don't remember where or I would link to it)

There is(or was) a bug that removes your password when you set the automatic login.
open a terminal and type to following.

- `passwd {username}`
- replace {username} with your username NOTE THE SPELLING: **passwd** (no "**or**")
- it will ask you for your current password just press enter.(your password should be blank due to the bug)
- it will then ask you for your new password type it and press enter
- it will ask you to enter it again, do so and press enter.
- It should then tell you your password has been updated, you should then be able to use your password as needed.

This is the easiest way to reset your password **but**, if you get errors, you will need to reset your password with the rescue shell, that answer is [HERE](https://askubuntu.com/a/24024/65969).

Comment: thanx TrailRider that worked

Comment: Well, if you do end up find it later, I recommend editing your answer to include a link to it.